# How to use a relation to filter a GROUP?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Let's say I have relation A

```
DUMP A;
(a)
(d)
(g)
```

And now I want to use A's values to filter a group G:

```
DUMP G;
(a, {(a,b), (a,c)})
(c, {(c,d), (c,x)})
(d, {(d,b), (d,e)})
```

...So that the result would be

```
(a, {(a,b), (a,c)})
(d, {(d,b), (d,e)})
```

And then I want to extract the groups to generate:

```
 (a,b)
 (a,c)
 (d,b)
 (d,e)
```

I tried the following to the filtering part, but it didn't work:

```
J = JOIN G BY group, A BY a1;
R = FOREACH (FILTER J BY J::group == A::a1)
    GENERATE FLATTEN(J.group);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the output of `J` should already be what you want.  By default `JOIN` is an inner join, so since `c` does not appear in `A` it will not be included in the output of `J`.  If you dump `J` you should see:

```
(a, {(a,b), (a,c)}, a)
(d, {(d,b), (d,e)}, d)
```

(Or something similar with the location of the variables switched.)

To `FLATTEN` out the bag you'll need to do something like:

```
R = FOREACH J GENERATE FLATTEN(G::FOO) ;
```

In this case `FOO` is the name of the relation you did the `GROUP` on.  You can verify its name with `DESCRIBE G ;`.